# What do we do with all these unanswered Flash questions?

Tags: discussion

So it seems we have a bunch (around 100) of unanswered Adobe Flash questions:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/flash?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50

A bunch of these are bug reports, and are pretty much unanswerable, considering that Flash on linux is basically abandoned, so what should we do? Perhaps a new canonical question? If so, which question should be start consolidating these into?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I've <strike>stolen</strike> repurposed this question as a canonical one:

- [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

Feel free to flag all the unanswered ones as duplicates, or if appropriate, a merge. Since there's so many I'm not going to waste my flags on them (I need them for the review queue) so I'm just going to wail on the moderator queue for a while (mwahaha).

Comment: Did about 20 of them (No more flag points). There might be more that do not have the flash tag.

Comment: Removed the flash tag i several that were using it for either USB Drives or mentioning flash in a series of problems that do not involve Flash as the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't we close them as off-topic? Flash is a buggy piece of software. They are bugs. They fit the description of bugs. Therefore, they are bugs.

If it looks like a bug (check), smells like a bug (check), and acts like a bug (double check), then call it a bug imo.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of a canonical question like we have for "black screen on boot" that is more of a collection of the workarounds, and then close everything to that.

Comment: Maybe this one? http://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues